# Why does firebase warn "* You are currently outside your home directory" during an init?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to deploy my first firebase app. I am getting the message "* You are currently outside your home directory" I googled it and found this reply

"commented on Dec 6, 2016
Just to make sure you're aware. If someone is experiencing the same problem with with the command firebase init
Make the files .firebaserc and firebase.json manually and the deploy should work normally."

I do not know where to create them or what the should contain.

I have also gone to https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools to try to fix this problem.

If any one can help with this problem I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone else worried about this just keep going. I continued with the deployment and it deployed OK.

Answer (score 1):

1. download firebase CLI binary (in case you didn't download it yet. this is an .exe file if you use windows).
2. copy the downloaded file into your project's root folder (Folder which contains all the files and folders of your projects).
3. run the firebase-tools-instant-win_2.exe (firebase CLI binary).
4. a command window will open.
5. execute all your command in there.

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize a Firebase project**
Many common tasks performed using the CLI, such as deploying to a Firebase project, require a project directory. You establish a project directory using the firebase init command. A project directory is **[usually the same directory as your source control root](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/)**, and after running **firebase init, the directory contains a firebase.json** configuration file.

To initialize a new Firebase project, run the following command from within your app's directory:

Comment: This was confusing to me too. basically your root directory of your project. I am amazed people come and be simplified with instructions

Answer (score -1):

I used `firebase init project` in my project's directory to get it to work